# Generate Multiple Scripts from SQL Server Query Optimizer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization, sql-scripts

I looked around but couldn't find an answer to this question so I figured I would ask.  So I am in the process of using the SQL Server query optimizer on several long stored procedures.  When the optimizer is done, that am getting lots of suggestions to create stats and indexes but it is displayed on one line at a time.

Is there a way to create all of the scripts at once?  Then I copy have to click each line to create my scripts and then copy to clipboard and then execute each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to this.   In the Database Engine Tuning Advisor, Under the Actions menus > Save Recommendations.

This will save all of the scripts in one file